# cannot find WebDriverWait api in selenium-webdriver when using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, selenium-webdriver

I am automating the various functionalities of the  mobile app using Typescript+Appium+SeleniumWebdriver+nodejs for this I need to use WebDriverWait

I am unable to use the WebDriverWait as when I try to import it errors out
So if I use `import {WebDriverWait} from 'selenium-webdriver';`

what I have tried is to first uninstall the `selenium-webdriver` and installed it back but still see this issue

```
npm uninstall selenium-webdriver
npm install selenium-webdriver@3.6.0



import {WebDriverWait} from 'selenium-webdriver';
```

this does not work :

```
WebDriverWait' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Module '"../../../../../../../../../******/****/node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver"' has no exported member 'WebDriverWait'.ts(2305)
```

Answer (score 1):

> `node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver` has no exported member 'WebDriverWait'

This error means that the types for selenium-webdriver were found, but the specific item you're trying to import isn't included in them.

You can check the types by opening `index.d.ts` in that path, or via github here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts

The error is correct: WebDriverWait isn't there. That either means that the types are wrong (always possible: they're written by hand), or that this property really doesn't exist.

In this case, it's the latter: `WebDriverWait` isn't exported by the module at all. You can see this by testing with:

- Run `npm install selenium-webdriver`
- Start `node`, and run:

  ```
  > require('selenium-webdriver').WebDriverWait
  undefined
  ```

I suspect you're following a guide for Python or Java, which do use this name when waiting on certain conditions. In JavaScript (and thus in TypeScript too) you don't need that. Instead, to wait for a condition you just need to run something like:

```
driver.wait(until.titleIs('My Title'), 1000);
```

It doesn't look like the current [Selenium docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) cover this case for JS, but the readme on npm has some useful examples: https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver